# Method in Intent Extra?

Tags: android

In my app I launch a new activity on the click of an image button and I was wondering if there is a way to launch a specific method in this new activity by using an intent extra? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way is to put an int as the intent extra and make the int determine what method the new activity calls. So, if the int is 0, run method0, if it's 1, run method1, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use different actions for the same Intent. Check the action in your onResume() method.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. start the activity with that intent and by parsing the extras you can route your code logic accordingly. Chrck Intent extra on the dev guide, google and here on stackoverdlow... You put the extras in the intent used to call the activity.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#iobjs